# Can BTT detect mouse cursor moved to different monitor on another computer via Synergy?

Tags: mac, bettertouchtool

I am using the BetterTouchTool and I have a question about that.

Actually, I would like to run some shell script to change some of the key mappings on another computer. So can BTT detect mouse cursor moved to a different monitor on another computer via Synergy?

The Synergy app allows sharing a mouse and keyboard across computers. Synergy software shares one mouse & one keyboard between multiple computers & monitors. Easy download, install & configuration. A Symless product.

https://symless.com/synergy

My synergy setup: Mac (2019 late, Big Sur) as a server, Linux (CentOS 7) as a remote client.

Thanks,

Arsene